# What is a heavy weapon?

Tags: horizon-zero-dawn

I saw a skill that said when holding heavy weapons you move faster. So I've been going to traders and looking for them.

Are they guns? If so I never knew they had guns in the game.

Comment: I'm guessing the downvotes are because this question is easily researched via Googling obvious keywords in your title. "horizon zero dawn heavy weapons" pulls up a dozen or so pages that answer this question.

Answer (score 10):

There are some heavy weapons in the game that cause Aloy to move slower. They have a lot of limitations - you can't jump/crouch while holding them, they get dropped if you dodge, and their ammo can't be refilled once they're empty. However, they do a lot of damage.

Here is a list of the heavy weapons in the game according to the [wiki](http://horizonzerodawn.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Heavy_Weapons):

- [Deathbringer Gun](http://horizonzerodawn.wikia.com/wiki/Deathbringer_Gun)
- [Disc Launcher](http://horizonzerodawn.wikia.com/wiki/Disc_Launcher)
- [Firestriker](http://horizonzerodawn.wikia.com/wiki/Firestriker)
- [Mine Launcher](http://horizonzerodawn.wikia.com/wiki/Mine_Launcher)
- [Oseram Cannon](http://horizonzerodawn.wikia.com/wiki/Oseram_Cannon)
- [Ravager Cannon](http://horizonzerodawn.wikia.com/wiki/Ravager_Cannon)

Answer (score 8):

They are simply weapons that Aloy can pick up and use, but are temporary/not part of your inventory.

They are:

- Deathbringer Gun
- Oseram Cannon
- Ravager Cannon
- Firespitter
- Firestriker
- Disc Launcher
- Mine Launcher*

* - Frozen Wilds expansion

Sources:
http://horizonzerodawn.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Heavy_Weapons
http://horizonzerodawn.wikia.com/wiki/Weapons